# Unable to include column if all rows are zero in pandas crosstab

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab, zero

In pandas crosstab, now I am getting the output as below if the other col contains all zero value:

```
  0
0 5
1 2
```

But I need to get an output for the other column even if it contains all zero.

```
  0 1
0 5 0
1 2 0
```

I am using below code to create cross tab:

```
data_crosstab = pd.crosstab(data[df_all.columns[56]],
                                    data[df_all.columns[57]], 
                                       margins = False,dropna=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
#margins=False is default value, so removed
#https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html
data_crosstab = pd.crosstab(data[df_all.columns[56]],
                            data[df_all.columns[57]], dropna=False)

data_crosstab = data_crosstab.reindex(columns=[0,1], fill_value=0)
```

More general solution:

```
data_crosstab = data_crosstab.reindex(columns=[0,1],index=[0,1], fill_value=0)
```